# How to store lispbuilder-sdl:colors in a list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sdl

I trying to store two colors in list:

```
(defparameter *colist* '(sdl:*black* sdl:*red*))
```

Printing sdl:color will return color in sbcl console

```
(print sdl:*black*) ;;#<LISPBUILDER-SDL:COLOR {1001E980A3}>
```

But if I try to print color from list I got different result

```
(print (car *colist*)) ;;LISPBUILDER-SDL:*BLACK*
```

How can I get  from list?

Comment: You need to use `(list sdl:*black* sdl:*red*)` instead of quoting. Quoted lists are not evaluated, so it contains symbols, not their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in first comment it is necessarily to use (list a b c) form.